# What makes a diatomic bond strong?

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

What are the factors affecting the strength of bonds? 
Ex:- why, we need less amount of energy to break Br-Br bond than Cl-Cl bond?

Answer (score 2):

In general, halogens naturally exist as diatomic molecules, bonded to each other with a covalent bond (a chemical bond that involves the sharing of electron pairs between atoms). Three of main factors affecting the strength of covalent bond are the bond length, bond order, and the electronegativity difference between the two bonded atoms if they are different (*e.g.*, $\ce {H-Cl}$, $\ce {H-Br}$, etc.).  Two atoms with equal electronegativity would make nonpolar covalent bond such as $\ce {Cl-Cl}$ and $\ce {Br-Br}$. Since two bonds in question are single bonds, the strength of covalent bond affected by bond order will not be discussed here. In general, though, keep in mind that triple bonds are stronger than double bonds and both of them are stronger than single bonds.

The higher bond strength in $\ce {Cl-Cl}$ than that of $\ce {Br-Br}$ can be explained by simply considering the difference in their bond lengths. You can easily find the gas phase bond lengths of $\ce {Cl-Cl}$ and $\ce {Br-Br}$ are equal to $\pu {199 pm}$  and $\pu {228 pm}$, respectively by a quick search on bond lengths online [Halogens]. The respective bond energies for $\ce {Cl-Cl}$ and $\ce {Br-Br}$ bonds are recorded as $\pu {243 kJ/mol}$ and $\pu {193 kJ/mol}$, respectively.

[Halogens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen)

Answer (score 0):

the strength of bond has a close link to atomic radii and the shielding affect.

in the example of halogens, a Br-Br bond is weaker than a Cl-Cl bond as  each bromine atom has an extra shell of electrons meaning that there is less of an electrostatic attraction between the pair of bonding electrons and the nuclei of the molecules. therefore, the chlorine is stronger as there's a stronger attraction between the bond pair of electrons and the two nuclei.